# How to stop auto sizing UITableViewCell from animating the resizing?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios8.1

All the examples I have looked work well if the UITableViewController were the first view to show a UITableView with variable cell height.  However, the same approach does not work when I push from one table to another one, which has the variable cell height.

I put up an [example](https://github.com/5amfung/SelfSizingCellDemo) on github. Feel free to download and mess with it.

When you tap on Click me, the table pushes to another table view which has the cells with variable height.  As soon as the second table is finished displaying, you can see the cell resizing in action, especially the cells that have more content it them.  Seeing the resizing live is annoying in this case.  I want the cells to be properly resized before they are shown.

Does anyone have similar problem or solution?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need some of the code you have in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and it would be better to set numberOfLines either in IB or in your cell code. I changed cellForRowAtIndexPath to be as below, and added code in the cell as follows,

In the cell.m,

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    self.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    self.subTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath,

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCell
        let content = self.data[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel.text = content.line1
        cell.subTitleLabel.text = content.line2
        return cell;
    }
```

Without the layoutIfNeeded in the cell code, I didn't see any expanding rows when the second table was shown -- only after scrolling or rotation. With it, everything seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to MyCell.swift seems to eliminate the live resizing issue as well.  I don't know how this is really different from @rdelmar solution, but this seems to work as well.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.titleLabel.frame.size.width
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```

I found this answer from [Advanced Auto Layout Toolbox](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html) under Intrinsic Content Size of Multi-Line Text.

```
Since we usually don’t know this value in advance, we need to take a two-step approach to
get this right. First we let Auto Layout do its work, and then we use the resulting frame
in the layout pass to update the preferred maximum width and trigger layout again.
```

Comment: What's really odd is that this solution works fine in iPhone 6 simulator, but you could see the live resizing in iPhone 5s simulator.